# Powershell remote software uninstall

Tags: powershell, uninstall, remote

I am trying to uninstall one or more software from a list of remote computers in our domain.

I have tried both invoke-command and enter-pssession, followed up by the following command which does not seem to work.

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c,$($quietuninstallString)" -verb RunAs
```

where $quietuninstallstring is something like: "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\unins000.exe" /SILENT

I have tried turning on/off UAC, running with/without the Verb RunAs admin, different software and remote PCs.

Is there anything I am missing here? Grateful if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please add the error you get (or if you get no error at all)

Answer (score 0):

To execute a file from powershell, use `&` or `Start-Process` instead of cmd:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Example' -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\windows\System32\HOSTNAME.EXE' '/?'}
```

or

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Example' -ScriptBlock {& "$($quietuninstallString)" '/c'}
```

If the user is an administrator on the remote machine, this will work fine.

Make sure you are setting the variable on the remote machine. You also want to make sure flags like `/SILENT` are in their own quotes fed to `&` (I'm assuming you want both `/SILENT` and `/c` here):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Example' -ScriptBlock {
  $UninstallPath = "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\unins000.exe"
  & "$UninstallPath" '/SILENT' '/c'
}
```

You can also specify a variable on your local machine in these cases with the `$Using:varname` structure (see [Remote Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7).)

```
$UninstallPath = "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\unins000.exe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Example' -ScriptBlock {& "$($Using:UninstallPath)" '/SILENT' '/c'}
```

Comment: hi @user19702, thank you for your response. 
My command is actually part of a function that i am calling from the invoke-command. It looks like : 

`Invoke-Command -computername 'RemotePC' -scriptblock ${Function:remote-uninstall}`


Within that function, i had the command for the uninstall. 

Following your comment, i have changed it to this but still the same issue. The command does not run and there is no error shown.This is what i have now:

`Start-Process -filepath "$($uninstallstring.exe)" -argumentlist "/SILENT" .`

Comment: @KK81 I've added a possible reason for this to the answer

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the command you specified but it didn't work. Meanwhile, I have tested my script on 5 machines, it worked on 3 but didn't work on 2 computers. Is there a cmd/powershell settings that might be blocking it for the 2 failed ones?

Comment: @KK81 Did you get an error? Did the script connect and seem to execute something? Can you run the command manually in a remote session (`Enter-PSSession MyPC`)? Maybe your uninstaller is asking you for input on those three (not running silently)? You will have to investigate.

Comment: Hi @User19702, I have tried to run it from Enter-PSSession but got the same result. It seems the command never executes. I don't see any error but then again if there is any error, it should be logged in the remote machine i guess. I have checked EventLog but didn't find anything specific.